# OnNavigatedTo is not called when using NavigationService.SelectTabAsync

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

According to the [documentation](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/navigation/working-with-tabbedpages.html#selecting-a-tab) of Prism "when selecting a tab programmatically both the INavigationAware and IConfirmNavigation interfaces are invoked". But unfortunately this is not the case for me.

I did the following with Prism.DryIoc.Forms v7.2.0.1422 (also latest version did not work) and Xamarin.Forms v4.8.0.1560:

My MainPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage
    x:Class="SampleApp.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:prim="http://prismlibrary.com"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:SampleApp.Views;assembly=SampleApp"
    Title="{Binding Title}">

    <NavigationPage Title="Page A">
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:APage Title="Page A" />
        </x:Arguments>
        <NavigationPage.Behaviors>
            <prim:NavigationPageActiveAwareBehavior />
        </NavigationPage.Behaviors>
    </NavigationPage>
    <NavigationPage Title="Page B">
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:BPage Title="Page B" />
        </x:Arguments>
        <NavigationPage.Behaviors>
            <prim:NavigationPageActiveAwareBehavior />
        </NavigationPage.Behaviors>
    </NavigationPage>
    <NavigationPage Title="Page C">
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:CPage Title="Page C" />
        </x:Arguments>
        <NavigationPage.Behaviors>
            <prim:NavigationPageActiveAwareBehavior />
        </NavigationPage.Behaviors>
    </NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

In BPageViewModel selecting tab "APage" with NavigationParameters:

```
private async Task SayHelloOnPage()
{
   var navParam = new NavigationParameters
   {
      { "SayHelloTo", "Prism" }                        
   };
   await NavigationService.SelectTabAsync(nameof(APage), navParam);       
}
```

In APageViewModel override OnNavigatedTo method:

```
public override void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
{
   base.OnNavigatedTo(parameters);

   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"OnNavigatedTo is called", nameof(APageViewModel));

   if (parameters.ContainsKey("SayHelloTo"))
   {
       var name = parameters["SayHelloTo"] as string;
       if (name != null)
       {
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Say Hello to {name}", nameof(APageViewModel));
       }
   }
}
```

See also this example project on my [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ys69041mlr8xmdn/AACaLq2pJVhyHvTqbxKSiwoMa?dl=0)

Is this a bug or do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug, or at least an oversight in the API. It does call `OnNavigatedTo`, but only on the `Page` that is directly part of the `TabbedPage`. If you have your target page inside a `NavigationPage`, only the `NavigationPage` will get the `OnNavigatedTo` call. See https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/src/Forms/Prism.Forms/Navigation/TabbedPages/INavigationServiceExtensions.cs#L73-L74 .

I worked around this by copying the above implementation to my project and then changing the behaviour to instead call `OnNavigatedTo` on the relevant child page of the `NavigationPage`.